# Microsoft SQL Server Query Text Formatter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, editor

Does the text query editor in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 have a SQL formatter (like many other code editors for other languages, including VB and C# in Visual Studio)?

I want to go from this:

```
SELECT foo frOm bar where bar.arg > 5
```

to this:

```
SELECT foo
  FROM bar
 WHERE bar.arg > 5
```

Comment: No. Redgate has a product that does this or [there is one available online](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste your query into a new view definition and that does have a SQL formatter

Answer (score 2):

you can use this online formatter:

http://sqlserverlearner.com/online-tools/tsql-code-formatter